# Cannot find ~/.hgrc file after Mercurial installation via MacPorts

Tags: xcode, git, mercurial, macports

I installed Mercurial via both .dmg and using the MacPorts command "sudo port install mercurial" but for some reason it is not creating the ~/.hgrc config file. I'm trying to set up GIT on OS X 10.6.8 and am currently stuck at editing the ~/.hgrc file because it isn't there.

Comment: I fail to see the link between "trying to set up GIT" and installing Mercurial, or finding the ~/.hgrc that indeed is never created by such an install. Could you be more precise about what you are trying to achieve and what the issue is.

Comment: I'm following the Bitbucket tutorial for installing and setting up Git and they go into Mercurial for some reason. I see what you mean though - Mercurial isn't required, but I was just curious. I got it anyway. Just had to create my own .hgrc file and add the options there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it works the same way as in windows, creating a clone or installing mercurial will not create a .hgrc or mercurial.ini. Have you tried creating it?